# How to enable autologin on dropbox API

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am developing the API for dropbox in PHP,i have connected with the given steps and downloaded the files successfully but my request would be, when i am going to connect the api through calling one php file, it would be authorized using secret key, app key and token value and then waiting for authorize and force click to next for manual process if it is not in session.

I am going to setup this as deamon process, so i could not click every time manually while connecting the API on php, is there any possible way that need to be resolved for these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

The user only needs to authorize the app once.

Once you have an access token for the account you want to use, you can just keep using that access token indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is the manner it works now, is there any way to user do not authorize any time and do it this on programmatically?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... are you asking for a way to access a user's Dropbox account without their permission?